# Swift 4 - UISlider with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I am using AVAudioPlayer to play audio, now I am trying to user UISlider as the audio timeline

```
@IBOutlet var audioSlider: UISlider!

override func viewDidLoad() {

audioSlider.setValue(0, animated: false)
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: (#selector(PlayerController.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

@objc func updateTimer() {

        if(audio != nil)
        {

            audioSlider.setValue(Float(Int((self.audio?.currentTime)!)), animated: false)

        }

    }
```

But I don't think its working, my UISlider goes from the start to the end right away. I am expected a smooth transition with my UISlider

Here is how I am playing audio:

```
@IBAction func playButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        if(playButton.titleLabel?.text == "Play")
        {

            postPlay(postid: self.postid) { results in

                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    do {
                        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
                        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                    }
                    catch {
                    }

                    self.audio?.delegate = self
                    self.audio?.numberOfLoops = 0
                    self.playButton.titleLabel?.text = "Stop"
                    self.audio?.play()
                    self.playCount = self.playCount + 1
                    self.plays.text = "Total Plays: " + self.playCount.description

                }

            }

        }
        else
        {
            playButton.titleLabel?.text = "Resume"
            audio?.stop()
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UISlider expects a value between 0.0 and 1.0. To achieve this you must divide the current progress by the total time.

**For Example**

```
audioSlider.setValue(Float(self.audio?.currentTime! / self.audio?.duration!), animated: false)
```